# Audio hosted on Azure Blob storage occasionally stops playing

Tags: google-chrome, azure, html5-audio

This seems to only happen in Chrome (latest version 31.0.1650.48 m, but also earlier), but since it doesn't always happen it's hard to say for sure.

When streaming audio stored in Azure Blob storage, Chrome will occasionally play about 30-50% of the track and then stop. It's hard to reproduce, but if I clear the cache and play the file over and over again, it eventually happens. An example file can be found [here](http://p3urort.blob.core.windows.net/tracks/b2950243-167d-4147-b937-fd6ea5ec3d57).

The error is pretty much the same as what's described [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111281), but I've yet to see the problem on any files hosted elsewhere.

**Update:**
The Azure Blog log only gives AnonymousSuccess messages, no error messages. This is what I get:

1.0;2013-11-14T12:10:10.6629155Z;GetBlob;AnonymousSuccess;200;3002;269;anonymous;;p3urort;blob;"http://p3urort.blob.core.windows.net/tracks/bd2fd171-b3c5-4e1c-97ba-b5109cf15098";"/p3urort/tracks/bd2fd171-b3c5-4e1c-97ba-b5109cf15098";c377a003-ea6b-4982-9335-15ebfd3cf1b1;0;160.67.18.120:54132;2009-09-19;419;0;318;7663732;0;;;"0x8D09A26E7479CEB";Friday, 18-Oct-13 14:38:53 GMT;;"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.48 Safari/537.36";"http://`***`.azurewebsites.net/";

Comment: I got 1 min 33 seconds into the song and it happened to me. Have you tried enabling monitoring on the storage account to see if it gives you anything useful?

Comment: I only get log entries for AnonymousSuccess, as decribed under _Anonymous Get Blob_ [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/08/03/windows-azure-storage-logging-using-logs-to-track-storage-requests.aspx). Can't see anything funny with them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69954028/audio-stop-playing-after-few-mins-hosted-on-azure-file-storage

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to set the content type to `audio/mpeg3`

Here's how I do it:

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
blockBlob.UploadFromStream(theStream);
theStream.Close();
blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "audio/mpeg3";
blockBlob.SetProperties();
```

From here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0139d27a-0325-4be1-ae8d-fbbaf1710629/unable-to-load-audio-in-html5-audio-tag-from-storage?forum=windowsazuredevelopment

[edit] - This didn't actually work for me, I'm trying to troubleshoot, but I don't know what's wrong, going to ask a new question.

This mp3 only plays for 1.5 min and then stops.  When downloaded, the file plays fully...
https://orator.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/zenhabits.net.unsolved.mp3