# audio stop playing after few mins hosted on azure file storage

Tags: azure, file, azure-blob-storage, storage, azure-storage

I have few mp3 files stored on azure file storage. when try to play them in chrome browser with html audio tag, I see the audio stop playing after few mins. do I need to migrate them to azure blob storage for better streaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would get better streaming support if you move your audio files to `Azure Blob storage`, and store them as `blobs`.  Blob storage is designed for supporting streaming content. Read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction). Azure File storage is more for supporting migration scenarios, from on-prem to cloud, and to augment or replace file shares and servers.

Comment: 1) Yes you could use AzCopy or Azure Data Factory to copy files to the Azure Blob storage. 2) Azure CDN is best suited for streaming media files (audio, more specifically video) , however you still need to store the actual files in Azure Storage. The CDN gives chunking, caching, closer to user edge location etc, but origin is still Azure Storage.

Comment: From the pricing page, "When the Content Delivery Network receives a request for an object that is not at an edge location, it makes a request to Azure Storage to obtain the data. For Azure CDN from Microsoft, any data transfer from an origin hosted in Azure is *included* in the base Azure CDN pricing".

Comment: Accept my answer if useful, so that others can also benefit.

Comment: For Azure CDN from Microsoft, any data transfer from an origin hosted in Azure is included in the base Azure CDN pricing".  Does this mean there wont be any charge for data transfer between CDN and Storage if I host the azure CDN and azure storage in same region.

Comment: Azure CDN pricing varies based on the storage backend origin - it can be one of Microsoft, Akamai or Verizon.  If you choose to use Azure CDN from Verizon or Akamai, then data transfer charges apply in addition to CDN pricing. But if you use Azure CDN from Microsoft, it does not mention region, so you can store in any region, then the CDN pricing alone is applied. For more details, please see question 5 in Azure CDN Pricing [FAQ page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/cdn/).

Comment: may be one last question azure CDN for microsoft only support web delivery where as Azure CDN Standard from Akamai has support for media streaming which one would be preferable in my case @Anand

Comment: Refer this [comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-features) page from Microsoft. Based on the average file size, they give suggestions to choose the variant. Media streaming certainly supported in Azure CDN from Microsoft, it is also available in Akamai and Verizon options.